# Darkening the brightness of a normal? Flat shading

Tags: opengl, math, vector

I was wondering how you would go about darkening the overall brightness to a normal. I am using flat shading and am calculating surface normals. Would I just decrease the magnitude of the normal? I have tried subtracting from normal.x, normal.y, and normal.z but the effect is only darker when viewed from the correct angle.

Comment: Are you even using Shaders?

Comment: you mean like GLSL? The .fs and .vs files? No. Should I, how would that help?

Comment: @AlphaCentauriAB Which version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: @rhughes I am using 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to darken the flat-shaded surface by tweaking just normals you should multiply them by factor:

- less than 1 to make them darker (less responsive to light)
- more than 1 to make them more responsive to light (lighter only when lit)

However this is not going to work in all cases (e.g. smooth shading) because there normals get interpolated and normalized within smooth shading calculations.

Yet I strongly recommend to leave normals normalized.

**Proper solution** would be to tweak your ambient and diffuse lights brightness and/or your objects materials ambient and diffuse components.